# How to display Component when on hover list item in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make Alibaba clone web page in React.

When hover on a list item on the left, special mini categories should be shown on the right.
Have a look at the picture, I tried to use objects inside an array, but couldn't do.
Please help me!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try adding mouse event `onMouseEnter` on your list item then create a function to show the right component based on hover list item you can pass an argument to identify each list item;

`onMouseEnter={(e,id)=>{showComponent(e,id}}`

then use this id to show right component and make sure to hide all other component first you show